# How can I make a nicely aligned diagram like this in LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-cd

It is a pretty simple diagram, basically the result I'm trying to get is something like this:

[image: Desired diagram]

Where the three equations are aligned to the left. I've tried using TikZ and Tikz-cd, but this is the best I can get to (I use the hphantoms so the arrow is more to the left):

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzcd}[row sep = tiny, column sep = -1 em]
        \hphantom{a} \arrow[dd, leftrightarrow, bend right = 60] & x = \sin{t} \\ 
        \hphantom{aa} & \dfrac{dx}{dt} = \cos{t} \\ 
        \hphantom{aaa} & \dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2} = -\sin{t}
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{center}
```

Which produces

[image: the diagram that i get]

So neither the arrow nor the equations are aligned (however, aligning the equations is the important thing).

How could I make this better? Ty in advance.

Comment: I think using a normal `amsmath` environment like `align` and [tag:tikzmark] is the way to go.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You *could* do this with `tikz-cd`. Just use one column and set `text width=0mm`. But I would suggest that this would look better if the `=` signs were aligned. As @Qrrbrbirlbel commented, the `align*` environment together with `tikzmark` is the way to go.

Note also, that if you have additional columns, the `textwidth=0` trick will fail. Instead use `text width=2cm` (or whatever you choose) and add `start anchor=west, end anchor=west` to the arrow.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd, amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzcd}[row sep = tiny, text width=0mm]
         x = \sin{t}\arrow[dd, leftrightarrow, bend right = 60] \\ 
         \dfrac{dx}{dt} = \cos{t} \\ 
         \dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2} = -\sin{t}
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is perfect! I also looked up tikzmark (which I didn't know anything about) as @Qrrbrbirlbel suggested and managed to do it, so now I have both an answer using tikz-cd and in a more suitable/correct package. Thank you both!

Answer (score 7):

In both the following solutions, you'll see the value `.3333em`, this is the default `inner xsep` for nodes in TikZ.

Since we don't even have a node with the TikZmark solution we'll add that in manually. The TikZ-CD solution uses `inner xsep=0pt` to tightly pack the nodes together but uses `outer xsep=.3333em` so that the anchorborder lies where it usually would again.

### TikZmark

This allows the full control of `amsmath` (e.g. equation numbering).
The `\tml` (`l` for left) macro is a wrapper for `\tikzmark` that adds a horizontal space and shifts the mark by `.5ex` so that it lies in the middle of the line (and not at its baseline).

#### Code

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}
\usepackage{esdiff}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,arrows.meta}
\tikzset{tm/.style={overlay, remember picture}}
\newcommand*\tml[2][]{%
  \llap{\tikzmark[#1]{#2,baseline=-.5ex}\hspace{.3333em}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
             \tml{a} x & = \sin t  \\
             \diff x t & = \cos t  \\
  \tml{b} \diff[2] x t & = -\sin t
\end{align}
\tikz[tm] \draw[Latex-Latex]
  (pic cs:b) to[bend left=60] ({pic cs:a}-|{pic cs:b});
\end{document}
```

#### Output

[image]

### TikZ-CD

With TikZ-CD you won't get any equation numbering (though we could just put that all in a `equation` environment to get at least one number).

Notice the `{}` in front of the `=` in the second column. This makes sure the spacing around the `=` is right. (AMSmath's environments insert that automatically.)

#### Code

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{esdiff}
\usetikzlibrary{ext.node-families}% https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-ext
\tikzcdset{
  left connect/.style={
    bend right=60, Latex-Latex, start anchor=west, end anchor=west},
  align col/.style 2 args={
    /tikz/column #1/.append style={
      node family={
        text width=\tikzmatrixname-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn,
        text width align=#2}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzcd}[
  row sep=0pt, column sep=0pt, nodes={inner xsep=0pt, outer xsep=.3333em},
  align col=1right, align col=2left,
]
  x \ar[dd, left connect] & {} = \sin t \\
                \diff x t & {} = \cos t \\
             \diff[2] x t & {} = -\sin t
\end{tikzcd}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

#### Output

[image]

Comment: I've also used `esdiff` like the others. Seems like a small but helpful package in writing derivatives.

Answer (score 6):

A bit less simple (short) solution with use of the `\tikzmarknode` defined in Ti*k*Z library `tikzmark`, as suggested by @Qrrbrbirlbel in his comment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}           % <---
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                tikzmark}   % <---
\tikzset{>=Straight Barb,
         is/.style = {inner xsep=3pt}
         }

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{esdiff}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\tikzmarknode[is]{a}{x} & = \sin t \\
        \diff x t   & = \cos t \\
\tikzmarknode[is]{b}{\diff[2] x t} & = -\sin t
\end{align*}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\draw [red, very thick, <->] (a.south -| b.west) to[bend right=45] (b.west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For final result you need to compile MWE three times.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

A simple solution with `pstricks`: I insert empty nodes at the beginning of the first  and third lines of an `align*` environment and connect them with an arc connection:

```
    \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{esdiff}
    \usepackage{pst-node}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{align*}
    \pnode[0, 0.5ex]{A}\hspace{1.7em} x & = \sin t \\
    \diff x t & = \cos t \\
    \pnode[0, 0.5ex]{B}\enspace \diff[2] x t & = -\sin t
    \psset{arrowinset=0}
    \ncarc[arcangle=40]{<->}{B}{A}
    \end{align*}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

A shorter PSTricks example. Run with `lualatex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{esdiff}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{align*}
        \rnode{A}{\phantom{d^2}x} &= \sin t \\
        \diff x t & = \cos t \\
        \rnode{B}{\diff[2] x t} & = -\sin t
        \nccurve[arrowinset=0,angle=180]{<->}{B}{A}
    \end{align*}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]